# post to php in android

Tags: c#, php, android

I wrote a Windows software that was sending information to a php page
Use the code below(C#):

```
string URL = "http://mydomin.com/page.php";
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

NameValueCollection formData = new NameValueCollection();
formData["INSERT"] = "DB";
formData["Title"] = subTxt.Text;
formData["Content"] = contentTxt.Text;

byte[] responseBytes = webClient.UploadValues(URL, "POST", formData);

string responsefromserver = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);

webClient.Dispose();
```

and in php:

```
if($_POST['INSERT'] != '')
{
    $subSended = $_POST['Title'];
    $contentSended = $_POST['Content'];
    ...
    ...
    ...
    echo "OK";
}
```

Please help me to implement this code in Android.

sorry for my english.

Comment: You have two real options. 1> look at [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/); 2> Go learn java and rewrite the question with what you've tried.

Comment: I worked with eclipse but I could not find an equivalent to this code

Comment: It would be quite hard to find exact equivalents to your code. You may look into this : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/  . I think this might help you get some idea about how to do the stuff you want in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try sth like this :

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://mydomin.com/page.php");

try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("INSERT", "DB"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Title", "YOUR TITLE"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Content", "YOUR TITLE"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```

Comment: and you can use Retrofit (https://github.com/square/retrofit)! it rocks!